# PostThreadMessage in .Net core 2.0 fails

Tags: .net, winapi, .net-core

I'm trying to use PostThreadMessage and GetMessage in .Net Core 2.0 but it fails.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool PeekMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool PostThreadMessage(uint threadId, uint msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 GetLastError();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MSG
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public uint message;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public uint time;
    }

    private static uint threadId = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mMsgThread = new Thread(MyThread);
        mMsgThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        mMsgThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        bool status = PostThreadMessage(threadId, 0, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Int32 err = GetLastError();
    }

    private static void MyThread(object obj)
    {
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        threadId = (uint)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        MSG Msg = new MSG();

        var RetVal = GetMessage(out Msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(RetVal);
    }
}
}
```

I get 'false' from PostThreadMessage, and GetLastError() returns 0 (instead of the real error).

**This code is working as expected on .Net Framework**

How can I run it on .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: Don't use `GetLastError`. Use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` for reasons that are explained in the documentation of latter.

Comment: Thanks! I got error 1444 - it means "Invalid thread identifier". I can see that the thread Id is wrong, I need a different way to get my thread Id

Comment: Likely that's the case. Notice that you had to suppress a compiler warning when you called `GetCurrentThreadId`. Since you are happy to p/invoke Win32 functions why aren't you calling the Win32 API `GetCurrentThreadId` directly? Of course, all of this assumes that the managed thread stays on the same native thread. Who says it does? Perhaps you need to reconsider your entire approach? Solve the problem by removing all of this pinvoke code and using straight up managed code. And then have the benefit that you aren't tied to a single platform, or implementation details.

Comment: As an aside, I'm sure you know that using `Sleep` isn't a proper way to perform synchronization, and that you just used it here when making a simple example. But I felt duty bound to mention this just in case.

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much, I wish I could avoid it and use only managed code, but unfortunately, I need to call native code.  I guess I can find a different way to communicate between managed code to native code. Maybe you can refer me to a good resource on the subject?

Comment: I can't see why you would need to be using `PostThreadMessage`. After all, even native coders do their best to avoid calling that function. And you are 100% sure that the managed thread always executes on the same native thread?

Comment: I am doing migration from old .Net code to .Net Core, and the old code uses it. What's the best alternative for interaction between C++ and C# in .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: Well, you aren't doing C++/C# interaction here. It's pure C# code because it's a C# thread. It's hard to advise on what to do with your real program because I have no details of its needs.

Comment: Yes, this was just a sample of the problem that I made from a very large code base that includes C++ and C# interaction. I understand now the problem of using this approach, and I'll find a better way. Thanks for your help

Comment: @giraffe_head Have you made any progress on this, it is exactly what I am stuck on. Trying to figure out how to retrieve messages from c++ window created from net core.

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius apparently the thread_id I gave from AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() is wrong, so I used the native GetCurrentThreadId and it worked. I did it by using: [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

Comment: @giraffe_head ,  have you managed for messaging thread run parallel to gui/main thread?  I've managed to get windows messages, but can't make it work on separate thread without blocking everything else.

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius my project is an ASP.NET core, so I have no UI. In my case it is not blocking any other threads